# Запаковка файла питон в исполняемый файл exe

Tags: python, tkinter, pillow

форумчане!
Кто знает как скомпилировать питоновский файл?

Просто я пытаюсь это сделать с помощью pyinstaller, но у меня не получается
Експерементировал: убирал разные библиотеки из кода, не компилирует только при библиоетеке PIL

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

а так всё компилирует

кто знает ещё способы откомпилировать файл питона, либо исправить ошибку

ошибка

```
L:\Програмирование\Python\Coder>pyinstaller main.py
99 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
99 INFO: Python: 3.7.4
100 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
107 INFO: wrote L:\Програмирование\Python\Coder\main.spec
110 INFO: UPX is not available.
111 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['L:\\Програмирование\\Python\\Coder', 'L:\\Програмирование\\Python\\Coder']
111 INFO: checking Analysis
124 INFO: Building because L:\Програмирование\Python\Coder\main.py changed
125 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
130 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
132 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3775 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
3779 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by d:\python\python3.exe
4134 INFO: Caching module hooks...
4141 INFO: Analyzing L:\Програмирование\Python\Coder\main.py
4649 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
6680 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
6681 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'd:\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
8516 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   setuptools.extern.six.moves
12119 INFO: Loading module hooks...
12120 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
12122 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
12246 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
12256 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "d:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Python\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "L:\Програмирование\Python\Coder\main.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 243, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 502, in assemble
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 410, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 377, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 793, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 407, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 907, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 732, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-numpy.core.py", line 27, in <module>
    pkg_base, pkg_dir = get_package_paths('numpy.core')
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 535, in get_package_paths
    file_attr = get_module_file_attribute(package)
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 318, in get_module_file_attribute
    loader = pkgutil.find_loader(package)
  File "d:\python\lib\pkgutil.py", line 493, in find_loader
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(fullname)
  File "d:\python\lib\importlib\util.py", line 94, in find_spec
    parent = __import__(parent_name, fromlist=['__path__'])
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "d:\python\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32
```

Comment: дайте облако на файл, попробую

Comment: @finally [https://www.dropbox.com/s/g460r0r8brs0ynd/Coder.zip?dl=1], буду благодарен

Comment: @finally файл main.py

Comment: ну я попробую еще поиграться, а пока дело видимо в самом инсталере

Comment: @finally а ты не знаешь-ли, есть ли какие-либо аналоги pyinstaller?

Comment: попробовал, у меня вообще проблемы с зависимостями модулей, которых нет в проекте) что то странное..

Answer (score 1):

Всегда использую pyinstaller и все ок.

Устанавливал отсюда.
https://www.pyinstaller.org

Возможно что то не так прописываете.
Есть хорошее видео с достаточно понятным объяснением
https://youtu.be/CgCJwDjm_Cw

У меня получается при помощи следующих шагов.

1. cmd (открываем командную строку)
2. pip install pyinstaller (устанавливаем pyinstaller  если не установлен)
3. cd путь к файлу *.py (переходим в папку с файлом который будем конвертировать)
4. pyinstaller -F *.py (запускаем команду с именем файла -F - ключ создает один ехе файл со всеми необходимыми библиотеками и прочим)
5. В папке с проектом создались новые папки и идем в папку dist и там лежит скомпилированный файл.

Comment: Скачал твой проект по ссылке.
У меня скомпилировался без проблем. 
Сам не запускал.
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/hpGL/NwQo2c9kd

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/). По факту это "обернутый" в графику `PyInstaller`

Comment: пробывал, всё что связанно с pyinstaller не работает

Comment: у меня работает.

Comment: у меня тоже, только при условии что без библиотеки Pillow

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/432091)

Comment: @Bogdan это не ответ, а альтернативное решение.

Comment: @garrythehotdog главная претензия в том, что это ответ-ссылка. У нас такое не приветствуется. Хорошо бы основное перенести в ответ.